# Error "Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations." inside our sharePoint online SPFx project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sharepoint, spfx

I am working on an 1.14 SPFX web part, but inside the .ts file we are getting reference errors on almost all the libraries as shown in this picture:-

[image]

For example, on the first reference error `"Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.`.. i tried those commands:-

```
npm install react

npm install --save-dev @types/react

npm i @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9
```

but did not fix anything.. any advice on this please?

Thanks